# icon in address bar isn't showen with jdbcrealm in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, favicon, jdbcrealm

i am trying to do a website with icon in address bar. it works in regular website. But i'm trying to use realm in tomcat (to protected my resources), the icon is in public role without any limitations. 
But it doesn't load the icon in address bar (even after i logged in).
 
When i write a full path at the address line of my icon, i get the image on the browser. So i think that i have permission to load it. 
The path of icon is true, because i have another image in the same folder and it works.
So why it doesn't work?
And now my code.
the jsp code which defines the icon: this tag is written in head tag

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icon0.png">
```

and the public permissions in web.xml are:

```
 <security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>public zone</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/img/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
```

and the admin role has permision for all files:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>adminzone</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
  <role-name>admin</role-name>
  <role-name>student</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your config is fine.

You haven't mentioned which browser you are using but if it's Firefox it's probably a caching issue. There are a lot of articles about clearing the favicon cache of Firefox. Here is one: [Clear Favicon Cache From Firefox](http://www.ivankristianto.com/internet/browser/clear-favicon-cache-from-firefox/1666/). (I haven't tested.) Maybe restarting the browser also could help.